# How to make a collapsible Div collapsed by default on page load using Twitter Bootsrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsible div on my web page which works  fine when toggling between collaplse:

The problem is when the web page loads the "Plcollapse" Div is opened by default.

How can I closed the Div on page load

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#plcollapse">
    Create list
</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="plcollapse" class="collapse in">

    <form >

        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="Title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="plTitle" value="{{plTitle}}" id="titleInput" placeholder="Enter title">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="Description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="plDescription" value="{{plDescription}}" id="descriptionInput" placeholder="Enter description">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label>Add one or more ...</label>
                <textarea id="videolist" ng-model="videolist" value="" style="width:40%"></textarea>
                <a ng-click="arrangePlaylistVideos()">Click here to arrange videos</a>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="CreatePlaylist()">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing class "in" for your div

```
<div id="plcollapse" class="collapse">
   -----
</div>
```